# Delay when opening MS Excel file on my desktop

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lately, when I open a  excel file saved on my desktop, it takes a while to open the excel file. Why does it take so long to open? Is there a way to make this process faster?

Comment: How big is the file? In what proximity to your email server is your email client?

Comment: It is saved on my desktop. When I open the excel file it show one line every 30 second until it is finished loading the whole image. The file is only 275 KB.

Comment: How are you downloading it if it's already on your desktop? How old is the computer you are running Excel on?

Comment: Is it just one file, or ANY Excel file that has this problem? If you move it elsewhere on the hard drive does it open as expected?  Is your Desktop redirected to a server or alike?  If you log in as a different user, does it behave nay better?

Comment: Sorry, I should of just said it take to long to open. I had the computer for about 3yrs. This just recently started happening.

Comment: Any Excel file gives me the same problem. I do get the same issue when I log-in with a different username. An moving it to a different location on the hard drive make no difference, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the following

- removing all Excel add-ins
- set Excel data connections not to refresh on opening
- change calculation options from automatic to manual